# Elegant way to check if multiple strings are empty

Tags: string, go, is-empty

How can I check if multiple strings are empty in an elegant way? This is how I currently do it:

```
//if one required field is empty, close the connection
    if (registerRequest.Email == "") ||
        (registerRequest.PhoneNumber == "")||
        (registerRequest.NachName =="") ||
        (registerRequest.VorName =="") ||
        (registerRequest.Password =="") ||
        (registerRequest.VerificationId ==""){

        //Could not proceed
        w.WriteHeader(UNABLE_TO_PROCEED)
        w.Write([]byte("Unable to register account."))
        return

    }
```

Comment: I'd also suggest using `http.StatusBadRequest` instead of a custom variable/constant `UNABLE_TO_PROCEED` -- 1. it's standard, so much more readable (anyone reading your code will know what it does), 2. your variable violates two Go idioms: Don't use `_` in variable names, and don't use all caps.

Comment: An alternative way could be to add a metod for _registerRequest_ to check if any one of the mandatory fields is empty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note: You may use the solution below if you keep the "is-valid" condition in your handler, and also if you separate your condition into another function or method.

You can create a simple helper function, which has a variadic parameter, and you can call it with any number of `string` values:

```
func containsEmpty(ss ...string) bool {
    for _, s := range ss {
        if s == "" {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Example using it:

```
if containsEmpty("one", "two", "") {
    fmt.Println("One is empty!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("All is non-empty.")
}

if containsEmpty("one", "two", "three") {
    fmt.Println("One is empty!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("All is non-empty.")
}
```

Output of the above (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/m3wy_y4VzMJ)):

```
One is empty!
All is non-empty.
```

Your example would look like this:

```
if containsEmpty(registerRequest.Email,
    registerRequest.PhoneNumber,
    registerRequest.NachName,
    registerRequest.VorName,
    registerRequest.Password,
    registerRequest.VerificationId) {

    // One of the listed strings is empty
}
```

Also `registerRequest` is a kinda long name, it could be shortened to like `r`. If you can't or don't want to rename it in the surrounding code and if you want to shorten the condition, you could also do something like this:

If `registerRequest` is a pointer (or interface), you could also write:

```
if r := registerRequest; containsEmpty(r.Email,
    r.PhoneNumber,
    r.NachName,
    r.VorName,
    r.Password,
    r.VerificationId) {

    // One of the listed strings is empty
}
```

Actually you can do this even if `registerRequest` is not a pointer, but then the struct will be copied. If `registerRequest` is a `struct`, then you can take its address to avoid having to copy it like this:

```
if r := &registerRequest; containsEmpty(r.Email,
    r.PhoneNumber,
    r.NachName,
    r.VorName,
    r.Password,
    r.VerificationId) {

    // One of the listed strings is empty
}
```

Comment: Terrible name hasZero, correct name should be isNotEmpty (https://talks.golang.org/2014/names.slide#2) and registerRequest should be r, but  rename it in whole function do not make alias in if.

Comment: @lofcek `isNotEmpty` would be a good name for a collection to check if its size is greater than 0. `hasZero()` tells if the list of passed values **has** a **zero** value (the value being equal to the zero value of its type). About `registerRequest`: I agree.

Comment: @lofcek Although I agree that in case of `string` values, `containsEmpty()` would be more intuitive. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

As Mario Santini mentioned in comment, a way to increase testability, encapsulate this logic, and decouple it from your handler method (which judging by the number of fields looks like it is at risk of changing at a different rate than your handler) could be to put this logic in a function:

```
func validRequest(registerRequest ?) bool {
   return registerRequest.Email == "" ||
        registerRequest.PhoneNumber == "" ||
        registerRequest.NachName == "" ||
        registerRequest.VorName == "" ||
        registerRequest.Password == "" ||
        registerRequest.VerificationId == ""
}
```

This now supports very focused, table driven tests, that can exercise what it means to be a valid request independent of any method involving writing headers.

It allows you to verify the valid/invalid path of your enclosing function, but to have very focused tests here.  It also allows you to change what it means to be a valid request and verify it independent of your enclosing function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `switch`:

```
switch "" {
case registerRequest.Email,
registerRequest.NachName,
registerRequest.Password,
registerRequest.PhoneNumber,
registerRequest.VerificationId,
registerRequest.VorName:
   w.WriteHeader(UNABLE_TO_PROCEED)
   w.Write([]byte("Unable to register account."))
   return
}
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements